# Yii2 tries tu run migrations already applied

Tags: yii2

Recently a have run the php yii migrate/fresh command, later I added one new migration, when I tried to run this new one, yii marks as not applied the new migration and other 6, how can I avoid this? thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run php yii migrate/fresh and you will avoid that

[image]